# java inheritance of autowired properties

Tags: java, spring, inheritance

I have two classes:

```
@Transactional
public class A {

@Autowired
protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;

//other methods
}

@Transactional
public class B extends A {

    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    //other methods
}
```

Here I want to inherit property autowired into superior class, but I get NPE when try to use it in child class. Is it possible to inherit autowired properties using classic java inheritance?

**EDIT**: BUT if I delete it from property fields and put it directly into methods like *sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()* - it works!!!!

Comment: Spring can only process autowired fields of a bean object after that object has been initialized.

Comment: So what can I do here?

Comment: Why would you want to `Session` stored in a field?

Comment: Class B is DAO class. Class A is DAO class as well but store common methods while class B is extention.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Why should a `Session` be stored in an instance field. Whenever you need the session, presumably in one of its `@Transactional` method, call `getCurrentSession` and use it locally.

Comment: You could, conceivably, use [`@PostConstruct`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-postconstruct-and-predestroy-annotations). But in this case, it makes more sense to either inject the `session` itself; or maybe override the setter for `sessionFactory()`, but I like that less. That said, all of this is an It Depends thing, mainly on what the scope / lifetime of the objects is relative to one another and the transaction. Extrapolating from ORMs, the Session should be per-transaction, but using that in a longer-lived object is... tricky.

Comment: By tricky, I mean that I believe that what ORM support in Spring does is that classes that use a `Session` get injected with a proxy that then talks to the transaction manager and delegates calls to the correct session. For your own code, it's usually simpler to just have `A`, `B`, `Session`, and everything that depends on them be transaction-scoped. (This also probably means your code itself is incorrect, since `A` and `B` seem to be singletons, as is the Spring default, and can't reuse the same `Session` between transaction-scoped calls..)

Comment: Wow, @Sotirios Delimanolis, I deleted session from property fields and added it directly to methods using sessionFactory.getCurrentSession() as you said. And it works!!! WTF?

Comment: _Spring can only process autowired fields of a bean object after that object has been initialized._ Review the order of object initialization (parent class constructor, etc.)

Comment: Spring first initializes the object. `B yourBean = new B();`. It then applies injection. `yourBean.sessionFactory = someSessionFactory;`. But by that time, ie. inside `new B()`, you've already tried to use `sessionFactory`, without it being properly initialized. It's therefore `null`. Spring won't publish your objects until they are properly processed, so by the time you call your methods, the field will have been injected with the appropriate autowiring target.

Answer (score 0):

Create method call it for example init()  and annotate it with @PostConstruct. And initialize the session inside it

Answer (score 0):

> > Here I want to inherit property autowired into superior class

You can , but don't use it in constructor or method with @POSTCONSTRUCT....

Use in another method(this method execute after DI done by spring)